# Basic pygame menu with buttons

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to python and newer still to pygame. In my attempt to learn, I set to make a basic menu with buttons. Here's my code: (note, ui_plate, is a system that the buttons are based on, it keeps all the ui in the same relative positions and sizes, no matter the size of the window.)

```
#===Setup==========================================================================
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

global winW, winH
winW, winH = (960, 508)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((winW, winH), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("SMC")

run = True

#===UI plate=======================================================================

def ui_plate():
    global uiW, uiH, uiX, uiY
    if winH > winW*0.5296:
        uiW = int(winW)
        uiH = int(uiW*0.5296)
    else:
        uiH = int(winH)
        uiW = int(uiH/0.5296)
    uiX = int((winW - uiW)/2)
    uiY = int((winH - uiH)/2)


#===Button class===================================================================

class button:
    def __init__(self, action, actionParam, buttonPic, x, y, w, h):
        self.action = action
        self.actionParam = actionParam

        self.bx = int(uiX + (x * uiW))
        self.by = int(uiY + (y * uiH))
        self.bw = int(w * uiW)
        self.bh = int(h * uiH)

        self.buttonPic = pygame.transform.scale(buttonPic, (self.bw, self.bh))

        self.over = pygame.Surface((self.bw, self.bh))
        self.over.fill((0,0,0))

    def draw_button(self):
        if window.blit(self.buttonPic, (self.bx, self.by)).collidepoint(mouse):
            self.over.set_alpha(50)
            if click[0]:
                self.over.set_alpha(100)
        else: self.over.set_alpha(0)
        window.blit(self.buttonPic, (self.bx, self.by))
        window.blit(self.over, (self.bx, self.by))

    def click_button(self):
        if window.blit(self.buttonPic, (self.bx, self.by)).collidepoint(mouse):
            self.action(self.actionParam)


#===Button actions=================================================================

def screen_swap(screen):
    global current_screen
    current_screen = screen
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
def printT(t):
    print(t)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
def exit_loop(blank):
    global run
    run = False
#------------------------------------------------------------------------


#===Menus==========================================================================

def main_menu():
    global buttonList

    backGround_image = pygame.image.load('Background.jpg')
    backGround = pygame.transform.scale(backGround_image, (winW, winH))
    ButtonPic = pygame.image.load('Button.jpg')

    buttonList = [
    button(screen_swap, second_menu, ButtonPic, .1, .1, .1, .1),
    button(printT, 'Hello!', ButtonPic, .1, .3, .1, .1),
    button(printT, 'Hello my friend', ButtonPic, .1, .5, .1, .1)
]
    window.blit(backGround, (0, 0))
    for b in buttonList:
        b.draw_button()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------

def second_menu():
    global buttonList

    backGround_image = pygame.image.load('Button.jpg')
    backGround = pygame.transform.scale(backGround_image, (winW, winH))
    ButtonPic = pygame.image.load('Background.jpg')

    buttonList = [
    button(screen_swap, main_menu, ButtonPic, .75, .1, .1, .1),
    button(printT, 'Bye', ButtonPic, .75, .2, .1, .1),
    button(exit_loop, None, ButtonPic, .75, .3, .1, .1)
]
    window.blit(backGround, (0, 0))
    for b in buttonList:
        b.draw_button()


#===Main Loop======================================================================

def main_loop():
    global run, winW, winH, mouse, click
    ui_plate()
    backGround = 0

    while run:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        current_screen()
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                window = pygame.display.set_mode ( (event.w, event.h) , pygame.RESIZABLE)
                winW, winH = event.w, event.h
                ui_plate()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                for b in buttonList:
                    b.click_button()

        pygame.display.update()



#==================================================================================
current_screen = main_menu
main_loop()

pygame.quit()
```

if you want to run it, which I would hope you do, as it will help me show you my issue, just get two images, call one "Background.jpg" and the other "Button.jpg", exact dimensions don't matter.

So there are two main issues I have right now, first, when I hover my mouse over a button, it is very slow to update the image showing that the button is being hovered over, and when I click and release a button, it flashes for a single frame before showing the correct hover state. (Note, the issues are more apparent in larger window sizes)

So I need help getting that to be responsive and clean, and if it's not too much to ask, I'd also like to know how well written the whole thing is, what could be improved, etc.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.